# When a shared library is loaded, is it possible that it references something in the current binary?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld

Say I have a binary `server`, and when it's compiled, it's linked from `server.c`, `static_lib.a`, and dynamically with `dynamic_lib.so`.

When server is executed and it loads `dynamic_lib.so` dynamically, but on the code path, `dynamic_lib.so` actually expects some symbols from `static_lib.a`. What I'm seeing is that, `dynamic_lib.so` pulls in `static_lib.so` so essentially I have two static_lib in memory.

Let's assume there's no way we can change `dynamic_lib.so`, because it's a 3rd-party library.

My question is, is it possible to make `dynamic_lib.so` or `ld` itself search the current binary first, or even not search for it in ld's path, just use the binary's symbol, or abort.

I tried to find some related docs about it, but it's not easy for noobs about linkers like me :-)

Comment: That's what it does. But if it isn't actually *exported* in the binary then...

Comment: Really? How do I inspect this procedure or make sure? Didn't find anything about that in the man page of ld.so

Comment: That's because the loader is responsible for loading libraries, not performing symbol lookups. See the `dlsym(3)` and `dlsym(3p)` man pages.

Comment: I see, thank you! I can strace the binary to see this procedure, right? To confirm, this is the case even if dynamic_lib.so claims its dependency to static_lib.so in its header? (ldd output)

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never tried. Symbol lookups are the same regardless of what libraries are loaded.

Comment: Tried, strace will only give stat/open/mmap, not dlsym/dlopen because they're not syscalls (of course they're not :-(). So my current understanding is, if dynamic_lib claims its dependency to static_lib.so, static_lib.so will be loaded when dynamic_lib.so is required regardless of the symbol lookup. And when the symbol is being resolved and there're two of symbol A in memory (the binary and static_lib.so), it'll be undeterministic which one is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change library to not load `static_lib.so` but you can trick it to *use* `static_lib.a` instead.

By default `ld` does not export any symbols from executables but you can change this via `-rdynamic`. This option is quite crude as it exports all static symbols so for finer-grained control you can use `-Wl,--dynamic-list` (see example use in [Clang sources](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/4920d3228938c5ca6d6dd267da640e9ff65b6802/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp#L3180)).